# Count number of zeroes in number issue with code

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion

My code is counting the wrong number of zeroes in a read in text file and I'm not sure how to fix it. Random numbers are coming up either one more than what i need or not reading at all.  Can anyone help?

```
private static int count0(int n, boolean zero) {
  if (n <= 0)
    return 0;
  else if (n % 10 == 0)
    return 1 + (zero ? 1 : 0) + count0(n / 10, true);
  else
    return count0(n / 10, false);
}

public static int count0(int n) {
  return count0(n, false);
}

enter code here
```

Comment: ```count0(100, false)``` --> ```1 + count0(10, true)``` --> ```1 + 1 + 1 + count(0, true)``` --> ```3```.  I don't understand what you're doing with the ```zero``` arg.  You have already accounted for a zero in the ```1 +``` part of the expression,

Comment: You know that you can turn a number into a string, and then just count '0' chars?

Comment: Stringifying seems inelegant to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of 'zero', we have

> n is 0 --> count 0
>   otherwise add 1 if this digit is zero, and
>   count the zero digits to the left

```
private static int count0(int n) {
  if (n <= 0)
    return 0;
  else 
    return  (n % 10 == 0 ? 1 :0) + count0(n / 10);
}
```

This works for (say) original n = 10 but IMO does not work for original n = 0; the answer should surely be 1?  That is, 0 is a special case.  Both '10' and '0' have one zero.

Comment: This works and thank you for helping but I have a follow up question for me to learn a little more.  How can you write the code to have user input what digit they want to find?

Comment: The general rule here is "post a new question", and show what you attempted so far.  But you should look at the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class, in particular the [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) method.  You should also be able to find lots of examples of using a Scanner here on StackOverflow.

Comment: By the way, you should usually "accept" the answer that works best for you - it shows others that the question has been answered (and hands me a few 'reputation' points).

Comment: thanks, i posed another question and accepted your answer!